# enhance android application for the use of processor resources

Tags: android, performance, manifest

Is it possible to increase the resources priorities of the processor through code in order to increase the performance of the application?

I ask this because I have to perform processes in the main thread that slows down the application

I tried to optimize the code as much as possible and it improved but maybe it is possible to communicate with the operating system through a line in the manifest so that higher priority to the application.

Thanks in advance.